# Open another application programatically then closing it causes main app to freeze

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app FirstApp I have a floating button, when clicking on this button the following code launch another app "Second App":

```
 Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        if (launchIntent != null) {
            startActivity(launchIntent);
        }
```

After launching the SecondApp successfully and closing it the firstApp will freeze.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Please add all of your activity or fragment code here.

Comment: this code looks OK. The problem is somewhere else. How exactly you know that `firstApp will freeze`

Comment: When I close the second app and return to the first app, the app does not respond to any event, ex: I can't swipe view pager. Note: when i close it using back button there is no problem. The problem occurs only when I force close the app by swiping it from recent apps